# why is prev, curr, next necessary for an iterative solution of reverse link List problem?

Tags: python, linked-list

The classic entry problem of linked list:
Given the head of a singly linked list, reverse the list, and return the reversed list.

For example, Input: head = [1,2,3,4,5] Output: [5,4,3,2,1]

A very typical solution in python here would be

```
def reverseList(self, head):
    prev = None
    curr = head

    while curr:
        next = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next
    
    return prev
```

It seems to me that the following would 'work' too

```
def reverseList(self, head):
        curr=head
        while curr.next:
            tmp=curr
            curr=curr.next
            curr.next=tmp
        
        return curr
```

where I use only 2(tmp, curr) instead of 3(prev,curr, next) 'variables'(correct me if it is a wrong name to describe them). I know I didn't consider the end of the linked list should point to None. Yet doesn't it suppose to give similar result as the suggested solution? However, I got a runtime error for the second one? What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what happens in the second code version with a linked list of values 1, 2 and 3.

Before the loop starts, we have this situation:

```
 head, 
 curr
  ↓        
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐ 
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
│ next: ─────► │ next: ─────► │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

After the first iteration, one `next` reference has been updated:

```
 head           curr
  ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐ 
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
│ next: ─────► │ next: ─┐ │   │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └────────│─┘   └──────────┘
  ↑      ▲              │
 tmp     └──────────────┘
```

This already looks wrong, because we've lost any reference to the third node, which has become unreachable.
So once that `next` attribute was updated, all hope to get the reversal done is lost.

But also notice how in the second iteration, `curr` goes *backwards* in the list as it follows the updated `next` reference.
This is not what is supposed to happen. `curr` should keep moving *forward*.
Then it sets the head's `next` attribute to the second node, but this was already the case (no
reversal here!). And so `curr` will walk in circles without end.

#### Alternative

Compared to the first, working version, you can do with one fewer variable when doing a tuple assignment:

```
    def reverseList(self, head):
        curr = head
        prev = None
        while curr:
            curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
        return prev
```

To reduce it to just one variable (`head`), you may use a recursive solution:

```
    def reverseList(self, head):
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        head.next.next, head.next, head = head, None, self.reverseList(head.next)
        return head
```

Comment: for the last recursive one, after assigning head.next as none, why would self.reverseList(head.next) still be able to give desire result when is it in fact self.reverseList(None)? Correct me if I am wrong , thanks so much

Comment: The recursive call will never be made with `None` as argument, because it was already assured that `head.next` was not `None` by the `if` statement.

Comment: Then wouldn’t the recursion stop just at the beginning since one has called self.reverseList(None) ? Since one has assigned none to head.next?

Comment: If `head.next` is `None`, then that means the list has just one element (`head`), and there is nothing to reverse. In that case the `if` condition will be true and no recursive call takes place. This is intended. This is also the guarantee that the recursion stops at the *tail* of the list and returns it. If you call `self.reverseList(None)` then that is a special case. This is the only case where the `head` argument gets to be `None` -- when the list is empty. Also here the `if` condition will be true and `None` will be returned without any recursive call.

Answer (score -1):

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
list.reverse()
print(list) // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

```py
def reverseMyList(list):
    listReversed = []
    for i in list:
            listReversed.insert(0, i)
    return listReversed
```